# How to disable previously disabled selects after form submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, dom

I have a form with multiple selects.

Some of them are disabled because I don't want the user to modify the values.

But as it's a form and needs validation, I have to ensure that the `<select>` form field is submitted when it is disabled.

I have found a partial solution to this problem, which is as follows:

```
jQuery(function ($) {        
  $('form').bind('submit', function () {
    $(this).find(':input').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

The problem is that after form submission, I would like the selects that were originally disabled to be disabled again.

The selects are generated dynamically and not all of them are disabled, so I don't know the number of selects beforehand (it is variable).

Is there any possibility to disable the previously disabled selects again?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `data-disabled` property on all of them. Set it `true` on the disabled ones and `false` on the enabled ones.

During validation you can check for `data-disabled` and if its `true` you can enable the selects.

Similarly you can do the vice versa.

Example:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('form').bind('submit', function() {
    $(this).find(':input').prop('disabled', false);
    // Do stuff
    console.log('I did stuff')
    $('form').find(':input').each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).attr('data-disabled') == 'true') {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true)
      }
    })
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input data-disabled='true' disabled='true'>
  <input data-disabled='false'>
  <input data-disabled='false'>
  <input data-disabled='true' disabled='true'>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the inputs disabled automatically after form submission without clicking disable button?

Comment: @Cheknov The button was an example, you could simply put the code after the validation. I have edited the code above for you to see.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, now it's more clear. Unfortunately it does not work with selects on my end.

Comment: @Cheknov can you share some code which is causing the problem so that I can see if there are other complexities involved.